# mithril requires 'mithril' to be imported

Tags: mithril.js

I am writing a simple Mithril component, given below is the code

```
var m = require("mithril")

var MyComponent = {
    view() {
        return <button>Hello world!</button>;
    }
};

export default MyComponent;
```

My problem is that in this scenario I am not using ***m*** as required, however when I remove this the app does not run, I get the following error

***Uncaught ReferenceError: m is not defined(…)***

Comment: What are you using to transform the jsx into hyperscript?

Comment: 'babel-loader'

{
    "presets": [
        "es2015"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "transform-react-jsx",
            {
                "pragma": "m"
            }
        ]
    ]
}

Answer (score 9):

It complains when you remove the `m = require("mithril")` line because when the JSX is transformed it becomes invocations of `m()`.

```
var m = require("mithril")

var MyComponent = {
    view() {
        return <button>Hello world!</button>;
    }
};

export default MyComponent;
```

becomes

```
var m = require("mithril");

var MyComponent = {
    view: function view() {
        return m(
            "button",
            null,
            "Hello world!"
        );
    }
};

exports.default = MyComponent;
```

You can see the JSX transform live on the [babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=%2F*%20%40jsx%20m%20*%2F%0A%0Avar%20m%20%3D%20require(%22mithril%22)%0A%0Avar%20MyComponent%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20view()%20%7B%0A%20return%20%3Cbutton%3EHello%20world!%3C%2Fbutton%3E%3B%0A%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aexport%20default%20MyComponent%3B)